# Windows Universal App, could not add all required packages to project

Tags: c#, visual-studio

So with the release of Windows 10, I've now installed it along with Visual Studio Community 2015 with the plan of developing new Windows Universal Apps...

However, when I try to create a blank Universal App, this error occurs while creating the project:

https://i.gyazo.com/4199572c66648138c17f2fc2921c6fcd.png

(Sorry, can't post images).

Followed by these errors in the error output:

https://i.gyazo.com/3685ae972899ee7dbf9fafdd697d6f7f.png

I haven't done anything to the code. This is from a fresh install of Community 2015 and a blank project, based on the Universal App Templates for C#

I've tried reinstalling Visual Studio and repairing, but no luck.

Comment: Same  problem for me

Comment: VS2015 has a silly bug.  Well, many silly bugs.  Use Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > General > tick the "Save new projects when created" as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You have to save your project and then install UniversalWindowsPlatform with nugget package or type :

```
Install-Package Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform
```

In the Package Manager Console

Then, you can compile and launch your program.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was trying to add a new project to an existing solution.  I got the same error and also tried repairing VS, checking and unchecking "Save new projects...", as well as trying to install the dependency manually. What got it to work for me was adding

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform": "5.0.0"
}
```

to the newly-created project.json file.